# SQL one row equals to two merged rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hi I'm doing project in Java and i have two tables in SQL and i want to link data between them.

Here is my problem, the first table have 2 columns named name and surname , and the second table have a row `namesurname` (there are other columns in each table) where `name` and `surname` are connected.

**Table 1 :**

```
name -   Example         

surname  -  Something
```

**Table 2:**

```
namesurname - Example Something
```

How can i make a link between these two tables to display all data from **Table 2**. based on inserted name and surname in **Table 1**.

Comment: You should add a foreign key id to table 2 referencing table 1 and join them; OR you could use a JOIN to join surname and namesurname. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: @MeesKluivers thanks , ill try that

Comment: Please provide more information. Is table one have two rows or two columns? Please show the tables structure, at least the part your asking about. The answers seem to assume that you mean columns and not rows.

Comment: @Peter4499 yes columns ,my bad . - Table 1 columns :name ,surname, dateofbirth, address, phone ,mail. Table 2 columns :namesurname,time , date

Comment: @AKAlmb it still doesn't answer what types are involved? Are the names a varchar,char, etc.?

Comment: @Peter4499 all varchars

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

select * from 1.table
join 2.table on [2.table].namesurname = [1.table].name+" "+[1.table].surname

Comment: I tried that before but it wont work, i got syntax error message :(

Comment: @Peter4499 wrong entry : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table1.surname' at line 1....                                                                                     on this query-- select* from table2 join table1 on table2.namesurname=table1.name+" "+table1.surname